# Run function every 2 seconds until varible changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it so that the interval function stops running when theImage length is equal to more that 0,

My Code

```
var theImages = $('.awesome-slider .slides img');

function checkImages(){
    theImages = $('.awesome-slider .slider img');
    // other stuff happens here but only want it to run once
}

if(theImages.length == 0){
    window.setInterval(function (){
            checkImages();
    })
}
```

theImages lenght does become more than 0 eventually but why does the interval function keep running?

Comment: This is not correct code, please review it and post properly.

Comment: *"why does the interval function keep running?"* because you never cancel it... You never say for it to stop so it keeps going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearInterval()`

```
let interval = window.setInterval(function () {

                 checkImages();

                 if (theImages.length == 0) {
                   clearInterval(interval);
                 };

               }, 2000);
```

Comment: this keeps running too :/

Comment: @AlexK change it to `if (theImages.length != 0) {`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

```js
var theImages = $('.awesome-slider .slides img');

function checkImages() {
  if (theImages.length !== 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      checkImages();
    }, 2000);
  }
}

checkImages();
```

Comment: you don't need `clearTimeout` here, and the condition should be the opposite

Comment: @Alex K Dude, `setTimeout` is much simplier solution that `setInterval`. You should consider using it instead.

Answer (score 0):

use window.setTimeout instead of interval.

By definition, interval will keep on going if you don't explicitly close it. 
You need setTimeout which will run only once. After your image length test, you can create another instance if needed